# Creating protocol message diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to create small protocol message diagrams as seen in IETF documents (e.g. as in [CoAP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-core-coap-18#appendix-A)). Nice would be auto aligning depending the amount of text (bigger texts appear like in [CoAP HLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mietz-core-coap-state-option-01#section-3.2))

Example:

```
Client  Server
  |      |
  |      |
  +----->|     Header: GET (T=CON, Code=0.01, MID=0x7d34)
  | GET  |   Uri-Path: "temperature"
  |      |
  |      |
  |<-----+     Header: 2.05 Content (T=ACK, Code=2.05, MID=0x7d34)
  | 2.05 |    Payload: "22.3 C"
  |      |
```

Is there some package that would help?
**msc** and **pgf-umlsd** or **tikz-uml** didn't look right....

Alternativly I could "hand-draw" that using TikZ.
If there's no package to help here, how would a minimal TikZ example look?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Take a look at the following question, as it seems relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19847/how-to-make-multiple-lines-precisely-converge-in-one-point-on-an-axis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's easy to draw some diagram like that if you start placing comments and after that use them as references to draw message interchanges.

Next code shows a minimal example. I've used `matrix` to create all `comments` and `server` and `client` labels. Of course, you don't need to use a `matrix` and can place them using relative positions.

The tricky part is how to align message arrows with corresponding comment first line. May be there exist better solutions but I've used `\subnode` command from [`tikzmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library. It creates an internal reference inside every comment node.

Finally it's easy to draw message interchanges with the help of intersection coordinates (`|-` or `-|`).

This is a complete code for a minimal example:

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,tikzmark}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, % --- Dont' forget it with tikzmark ---
        comment/.style={text width=10cm, align=left},   
        font=\small\ttfamily]

    %Place `Client`, `Server` and `comment` nodes   
    \matrix{%
        \node (client) {Client}; & 
        \node (server) {Server}; & \\
        & & 
        \node[comment] (1) {\subnode{A}{Header}: 
            GET (T=CON, Code=0.01, MID=0x7d34)\\ 
            Uri-Path: "temperature"}; \\ 
        & & 
        \node[comment] (2) {\subnode{B}{Header}: 
            2.05 Content (T=ACK, Code=2.05, MID=0x7d34)\\ 
            Payload: "22.3 C"}; \\};

    %Draw vertical lines
    \draw (client) -- (client|-2.south);
    \draw (server) -- (server|-2.south);

    %Draw message interchanges
    \draw[->] (A-|client)--node[below]{GET} (A-|server) ;
    \draw[<-] (B-|client)-- node[below]{2.05} (B-|server) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Compile previous code twice to get

[image]

**Update**

If you want to align comments around colons, you can use a `tabular` inside comments.
In this case you have to use `ampersand replacement` option inside `\matrix` because it's necessary to have different `&` symbols inside `tabular` and `matrix`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, 
    comment/.style={text width=10cm, align=left},   
    font=\small\ttfamily]

%Place `Client`, `Server` and `comment` nodes   
\matrix [ampersand replacement=\&]{%
    \node (client) {Client}; \& 
    \node (server) {Server}; \& \\
    \& \& 
    \node[comment] (1) {\begin{tabular}{r@{ }l}\subnode{A}{Header}:& 
        GET (T=CON, Code=0.01, MID=0x7d34)\\ 
        Uri-Path:& "temperature"\end{tabular}}; \\ 
    \& \& 
    \node[comment] (2) {\begin{tabular}{r@{ }l}\subnode{B}{Header}:& 
        2.05 Content (T=ACK, Code=2.05, MID=0x7d34)\\ 
        Payload:& "22.3 C"\end{tabular}}; \\};

%Draw vertical lines
\draw (client) -- (client|-2.south);
\draw (server) -- (server|-2.south);

%Draw message interchanges
\draw[->] (A-|client)--node[below]{GET} (A-|server) ;
\draw[<-] (B-|client)-- node[below]{2.05} (B-|server) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is now

[image]

But, if you want to align all comments, it's better to put all of them inside a `tabular`. You can avoid using `\matrix` and place `server` and `client` labels after it. In order to separate different comments you can use `\\[vertical distance]` inside `tabular`.

Solution looks like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, 
    font=\small\ttfamily]

%Place a `comment` node with all text inside a tabular  
 \node(comments) {\begin{tabular}{r@{ }l}
        \subnode{A}{Header}:& 
        GET (T=CON, Code=0.01, MID=0x7d34)\\ 
        Uri-Path:& "temperature"\\[3mm] 
       \subnode{B}{Header}:& 
        2.05 Content (T=ACK, Code=2.05, MID=0x7d34)\\ 
        Payload:& "22.3 C"\end{tabular}};

% Place `server` and `client` nodes
\node[above left=1mm and 0mm of comments] (server) {Server}; 
\node[left=5mm of server] (client) {Client}; 

%Draw vertical lines
\draw (client) -- (client|-comments.south);
\draw (server) -- (server|-comments.south);

%Draw message interchanges
\draw[->] (A-|client)--node[below]{GET} (A-|server) ;
\draw[<-] (B-|client)-- node[below]{2.05} (B-|server) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The " symbol was conflicting with my babel package set to ngerman. But after using the solution from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117732/tikz-and-babel-error it works.

Comment: One last thing: How would you align the comment entries to have the colons in a row underneath each other?

Comment: @Lincoln: I've updated the answer with two possible solutions

Comment: Amazing...exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: I tried the third piece of code ('But, if you want to align all comments...') and got an error: `! Package pgf Error: No shape named 2 is known.` I changed `client|-2.south` to `client|-B.south` and `server|-2.south` to `server|-B.south` and that worked, sort of. The vertical lines stop just south of the the second, left-pointing, arrow. What am I missing?

Comment: Fixed. It looks like `|-2.south` should be `|-comments.south` Whew! Nice.

Comment: @sgmoye: You're right. I've already corrected the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the msc package (www.ctan.org/pkg/msc mirror.ctan.org:macros/latex/contrib/msc) seems to do what you want.

of course it's not pgf-sexy...